# Choose between the binary and souce lib

Tags: ros, build-from-source, ros-noetic, binary

I have installed `trac-ik` via `sudo apt-get install` and building from source, respectively, where the source code of `trac-ik` is installed in `~/ws_trac_ik/src/`.

I have made some changes to the source code of `trac-ik` and then made some executables to link against `trac-ik`. By default, `find_package` looks for `trac-ik` under `/opt/ros/noetic/`.

However, I want some executables to link against the source code of `trac-ik` that I have changed and change the link DIR to the binary installed path of `trac-ik` when necessary. Especially, I don't want to remove the binary form of `trac-ik`.

How can realize this process? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to make this a little bit more concrete about what you're doing, and what isn't working for you. And from that someone can hopefully help you. As written this is open ended enough that the answer has to be speculative about what your problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have edited my question.

Comment: Please share your progress so far. Also please show us your `CMakeLists.txt` file. In principle, you should be able to set `INCLUDE_DIRS`, `LIBRARIES` cmake variables as done [here](https://github.com/ravijo/ros_protocol_buffer_tutorial/blob/e0ae357f5b3438311bea5d7340826f31305ccf89/CMakeLists.txt). If it supports `find_package`directive, you can provide it a custom location as done [here](https://ravijo.github.io/pcl/).

Comment: @ravi Thanks for your help, I will give it a try.